# how to train a face-recognizer with new additional pictures?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

```
recognizer= cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
if os.path.exists("recognizer\\trainingData_LBPHF.yml"):
    recognizer.load("recognizer\\trainingData_LBPHF.yml")
IDs,faces=retrainer(directory)
recognizer.train(faces,IDs)
```

While I run this code my recognizer retrain on new pictures but lose everything that had been done before. Is there a way to retrain my recognizer on new additional pictures without retraining on the old ones in order to accelerate the processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`update`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#a8a4e73ea878dcd0c235d0487189d25f3):

```
recognizer.update(faces, IDs)
```

> This method updates a (probably trained) FaceRecognizer, but only if the algorithm supports it. The Local Binary Patterns Histograms (LBPH) recognizer (see createLBPHFaceRecognizer) can be updated.

Comment: thank you it works, but it seems that the recognizer is more likely to give the name of the new person who has just been registered than the real name of the person in front of him. More precisely, I mean that the prediction seems less precise for the former users.

Comment: That probably depends on the composition of your dataset, but this should be asked in a new question ;)

Comment: OK thank you I'll put more pictures in my database to avoid this. @Miki